# Why does JsonArray.Parse return me primitives with quotes?

Tags: silverlight, json

I expected the following code

```
JsonArray.Parse("[\"cat\",\"dog\"]")[0].ToString()
```

to give me `cat` but it actually gives me `"cat"`.

Is this a bug or by design.

Interestingly there is a private `value` member which does give `cat`.

```
 (((System.Json.JsonPrimitive)(JsonArray.Parse("[\"cat\",\"dog\"]")[0]))).value
```

will give `cat` - but its private !

*(JsonArray is in `System.Json.dll` which for Silverlight 4 is here : C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Libraries\Client\System.Json.dll)*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is by design.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.json.jsonprimitive_methods%28v=VS.95%29.aspx

> ToString Saves (serializes) this JSON CLR type into text-based JSON. (Inherited from JsonValue.)